# mysite.com/ returns 403 error when using RewriteRule to remove php file extensions

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm attempting to hide .php file extensions from URLs using the following piece of code in my virtual host's conf file (apache2). Works great, except for when a user attempts to load just the domain (www.mysite.com). Then a 403 error is returned.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it redirected root / to /.php. Fixed by exluding root folder

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```